# How to make responsive html table to match viewport initial scale 1.0

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table, viewport

In my website I have some pages consisting with header footer divisons and table, 
and I am using viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Html table is consist with so many column so in mobile devices it overflows to the screen.

To see whole html table visitor has to zoom out the webpage.

Like the image refers:

[image: IMAGE AFTER ZOOM OUT THE PAGE]

After zooming out you can see in the picture  header and div not expanding to match html table width.

And it remains short in width after zoom out, because I am using meta viewport for this and initial scale is 1.0

but I need result like this

refer image:

[image: THIS IS RESULT I WANT]

I need help regarding this- when webpage open in browser of mobile devices.

html table should shrink [zoom out] to device width and all other element should remains same in width or equal to device width.

I searched on net and I found this: [enter link description here](http://exisweb.net/responsive-table-plugins-and-patterns) 4. Responsive Tables

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap to cover those scenarios. Also, Css, to the image set to 100% with and height, or css tricks to accomplish that. @Media queries may help you to load or change the image dynamically for different device resolutions.

Other than that, I'm not sure if the problem you´re specifying is related to the default view that needs to zoom out as default or not.